# Pagination is not working with multiple endpoints in GetMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination

I’m trying to implement pagination in an existing codebase. I wrote this ExperimentService class:

`ExperimentService.java`

```
@Service
public class ExperimentService {

    @Autowired
    private ExperimentRepository experimentRepository;

    public Page<Experiment> fetchExperiments(Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize) {

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize);
        return experimentRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    public Page<Experiment> fetchExperimentsByKeyword(String keyword, Pageable pageable) {
        return experimentRepository.findByKeywordPage(keyword, pageable);
    }
}
```

The existing code I am trying to modify looks like this:

`Controller`

```
@GetMapping({ "/list", "/", "/search"})
public ModelAndView getAllExperiments(Authentication authentication,HttpSession session,@RequestParam(defaultValue ="0") int page,String keyword)
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("experiment");
        String loggedInUser = authentication.getName();
        //String loggedInUser = "kaufmafi";
        System.out.println("loggedInUser------"+loggedInUser);
        session.setAttribute("user", loggedInUser);
        try{
          int isCsmg = eRepo.isCsmg(loggedInUser);
          session.setAttribute("isCsmg", isCsmg);   
        if(isCsmg==1){
            if(keyword!=null){
            keyword =keyword.trim().toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("keyword------"+keyword);
            List<Experiment> proList1=eRepo.findByKeyword(keyword);
            mav.addObject("experiments", proList1);
            System.out.println("code name------"+proList1.size()+"name----------"+proList1.get(1).getCodeName());
            }
            else{
            //Page<Experiment> experiment = eRepo.findAll(PageRequest.of(page,10));
            mav.addObject("experiments", eRepo.findAll());
            }

        }else{
            if(keyword!=null){
            keyword =keyword.trim().toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("keyword------"+keyword);
            mav.addObject("experiments", eRepo.getExperimentsByKeyword(loggedInUser,keyword));
            }
            else
            mav.addObject("experiments", eRepo.getAllByuserId(loggedInUser));
    
        }
        
    }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        return mav;
}
```

I've modified the code as follows:

```
@GetMapping({ "/list", "/", "/search", "/list/{pageNo}" })
    public ModelAndView getAllExperiments(Authentication authentication, HttpSession session,
            @PathVariable("pageNo") Integer pageNo, String keyword) {
        // should use @PathVariable instead of @RequestParam

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("experiment");
        String loggedInUser = authentication.getName();

        System.out.println("loggedInUser------" + loggedInUser);
        session.setAttribute("user", loggedInUser);

        try {
            // initialize pageNo
            if (pageNo == null) {
                pageNo = 0;
            }
            int isCsmg = eRepo.isCsmg(loggedInUser);
            session.setAttribute("isCsmg", isCsmg);
            if (isCsmg == 1) {
                mav.addObject("experiments", experimentService.fetchExperiments(pageNo, 10));
                if (keyword != null) {
                    keyword = keyword.trim().toUpperCase();
                    System.out.println("\n\nkeyword------" + keyword + "\n\n");

                    //pass pageable to method
                    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo, 20);
                    Page<Experiment> page = experimentService.fetchExperimentsByKeyword(keyword, pageable);
                    List<Experiment> proList1 = page.getContent();

                    mav.addObject("experiments", proList1);

                } else if (keyword.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    mav.addObject("experiments", experimentService.fetchExperiments(pageNo, 10));
                }

                else {
                    mav.addObject("experiments", experimentService.fetchExperiments(pageNo, 10));
                }

            } else {
                if (keyword != null) {
                    keyword = keyword.trim().toUpperCase();
                    System.out.println("keyword------" + keyword);
                    mav.addObject("experiments", eRepo.getExperimentsByKeyword(loggedInUser, keyword));
                } else
                    mav.addObject("experiments", eRepo.getAllByuserId(loggedInUser));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return mav;
  
}
```

I’ve looked at this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/6.1-SNAPSHOT/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-requestmapping.html
to understand how to correctly setup multiple endpoints, which documentation doesn’t truly address; however, the paths are not working correctly. The issues I am facing are when the application is initially launched and logged into I receive the following error:

> Required URI template variable 'pageNo' for method parameter type Integer is not present
> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Required URI template variable 'pageNo' for method parameter type Integer is not present

but I am initializing the `pageNo` with a value of zero (1st page) in the `try catch` block.
2nd issue is the search criteria does not work when I introduce the new endpoint, what am I doing wrong?